# Laravel/Eloquent model with many-to-many and self-references

Tags: laravel, eloquent

An office has many employees, and an employee can work at many offices.

```
// office model
public function employees()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Model\Employee::class);
}

// employee model
public function offices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Model\Office::class);
}
```

Using this I can get a relationship and further filter is as follows:

```
$qualified = $office->employees()->whereHas('qualifications', function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('job', ['doctor', 'dentist']);
});
```

The difficulty is that some offices are too small to have their own employees, so we 'attach' them to one or more large offices, and let them 'inherit' that workforce.  We call the small offices 'minor', and the large offices 'major'.

```
// office model
public function majors() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Model\Office::class, 'attachments', 'minor_id', 'major_id');
}
```

When dealing with a small (that is 'minor') office, I need to be able to access the staff they inherit.  I have managed to do this as follows:

```
// office model
public function inheritedEmployees()
{
    $employees = collect();
    if ($this->is_major) return $employees;

    foreach ($this->majors as $major) {
        $employees->concat($major->employees);
    }

    return $employees->unique('id')->sortBy('first_name');
}
```

The problem is that `inheritedEmployees()` does not return an Eloquent Relationship, so I can't add additional clauses to it.

How can I alter `inheritedEmployees()` to return a relationship?

Comment: You can't. You can't make references to `$this`, referring to the model instance and return a relationship. Because `$this` in the context of a relationship is a query object, not an instance of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to actually return a relationship in order to chain methods to it; any query that hasn't been executed will return a `QueryBuilder` you can chain on.

Assuming you have the reverse `minors()` relationship (fetching the offices under the major office), you can try doing this:

```
// In the Office model

public function inheritedEmployees() {
    return EmployeeAssignment::query()
                ->where('office_id', $this->minors()->pluck('id'));
}
```

I've assumed you created a helper (`EmployeeAssignment`) class to model the pivot table between offices and employees (this will be useful to deal with complex relationships such as this one).

Comment: Thanks DfKimera, that's made my day!